# Is it possible to send an email based on Report results?

Tags: workflow, standard-objects, leads, notification

I have a certain report, that shows if there are qualified leads in the system, and alerts me on that. (theoretically - that should not happen).

Based on that report, there are from 1-6 users who own these leads.

Is it possible, that an alert/notification email will be sent to the owner of the lead, if his lead is in qualified status?

--EDIT--
I currently have a rule, that makes this alert on a single time when the lead goes into Qualified. I need this to work on a regular basis, and to keep nagging my users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how often you want them notified.

If daily is ok;
The best way to activate the users in this situation is to set up a leader board (name and shame) dashboard that is scheduled daily to email to the team.  If you are concerned about sharing that data, you could set one up for each user.
This will provide a daily reminder to the team who has outstanding leads to action.

If it needs to be less than daily;
You will probably need to schedule some code to run in your designated intervals to find if there are any qualified leads and notify the offending parties.

Comment: I have gone with this approach - Let the managers deal with it :-)

Answer (score 4):

This could be a Scheduled Apex Class. It could run once a day, or week, find all the matching Leads, group them by User and email each applicable user with their list of neglected Leads. It will remind them every day/week/whatever for an indefinite period of time until they fix the offending records.

This is not a huge amount of work, but if you don't need forever reminding, it might be easier to just build 3 or 4 workflow time triggers at different intervals, as suggested by @Nick Cook.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be a simple workflow rule triggered on the lead status going to Qualified?

You can also add time based workflow rules that will email the owner x days later. This is something I implemented for Opportunities nearing the close date. First email 7 days prior to close date, reminder on day of close date, then reminder again 7 days later. If the Opportunity still hasn't been updated, it appears on an exception report that the Sales Manager is responsible for.

Comment: This is true, but it's a one time action. I am looking for something that will "keep nagging" the users. My report runs on a weekly basis, and I want my users to get the reminder if they don't follow.

Comment: You can also add time based workflow rules that will email the owner x days later.
This is something I implemented for Opportunities nearing the close date.  First email 7 days prior to close date, reminder on day of close date, then reminder again 7 days later.  If the Opportunity still hasn't been updated, it appears on an exception report that the Sales Manager is responsible for.